# LeetCode # 274. H-Index, What is the time complexity of my solution?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm trying to solve a [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/h-index/description/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-interview-150) problem "H-Index" without using sort() method. **I want to know what the time complexity would be for my solution.** Below is the problem and my solution.

#### Problem:

Given an array of integers citations where citations[i] is the number of citations a researcher received for their ith paper, return the researcher's h-index.

According to the definition of h-index on Wikipedia: The h-index is defined as the maximum value of h such that the given researcher has published at least h papers that have each been cited at least h times.

Example 1:

```
Input: citations = [3,0,6,1,5]
Output: 3

Explanation: [3,0,6,1,5] means the researcher has 5 papers in total and each of them had received 3, 0, 6, 1, 5 citations respectively.Since the researcher has 3 papers with at least 3 citations each and the remaining two with no more than 3 citations each, their h-index is 3.
```

#### Solution:

```py
class Solution:
    def hIndex(self, citations: List[int]) -> int:
        space = []

        for i in range(len(citations)):
            if not space:
                if citations[i] > 0:
                    space.append(citations[i])
            
            else:
                if citations[i] > len(space):
                    space.append(citations[i])

                    if min(space) < len(space):
                        space.remove(min(space))

        return len(space)
```

Please help me!

Comment: @Cow What does that have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

At the first glance, it may look like your solution having the time complexity of `O(n)` but in reality, it is `O(n^2)`.

The operations `min` and `remove` iterates the array `n` times (inside the for loop) to look through the space which results in `n*n`.

One way to optimize your function is to modify the data structure and potentially use a *heap*, which can keep track of the min value in `O(1)` time and remove it in `O(log n)` time.
This could reduce the overall time complexity from `O(n^2)` to `O(n log n)`.

There is also the potential to get it down to O(n).

You can build a papers list of the citation counts and then accumulate from the end until it finds the `h-index`. It avoids the use of the `min()` and `remove()` that makes it more efficient and reduces the time complexity to `O(n)`.

This approach will use the amount of operations such as addition, comparison, etc inside the loop. It leverages the fact that `h-index` can never be greater than the total number of papers so it limits the count of citations to `n`.

Comment: Both min and remove are behind multiple ifs, though. How often can they actually be reached? You say "n times", but that's rather clearly not true.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop `for i in range(len(citations)):` is O(n) and inside it you have another indirect loop which is the `min` function.
Your total time complexity is O(n^2).